# How to avoid repeated matching items in Eclipse 'Open Resource'?

Tags: eclipse, maven, resources

The project I'm working in uses Maven and its typical standar directory layout.
When I look for a resource with Eclipse 'Open Resource' I get these matches:

[image: Eclipse Open Resource matches]

Where I get repeated matches.
There are only 2 XML files in filesystem.
The one under **src/** and the one under **target/**.

For example, the path to the src/ file is:

**maindev/common/utils/persistence/src/main/resources/com/ericsson/m2m/common/utils/persistence/impl/mybatis/custom/xml/**

But 'Open Resource' indicates 3 matches for the same file with relative paths:

- maindev/common/utils/persistence/src/...
- common/utils/persistence/src/...
- persistence/src/...

Is there a way in Eclipse to avoid those repeated matches?

Moreover, is there a way in Eclipse to indicate not to return resources for **target/** directories?

**NOTE:** I tried Wojtek O. suggestion, but still getting matches:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You see multiple files because they logically are contained withing difference Eclipse projects. You could try to close some of those projects but that may as well result in compilation errors. If you wish to hide some files from the *Open Resource...* dialog you need to mark the folder containg those files as derived by right clicking on it in the Project Explorer and selecting **Derived** checkbox under **Attributes** section.

Comment: Mmm, I did that, but I don't see any changes in 'Open Resource' results. Append new image. They still appear. Do you know what it means the ---Workspace matches---?

Comment: @tomasorti I think the problem here is that you are working with maven multi module project, and Eclipse treats every target folder separately, so you would need to go through all your projects (maindev,persistence,common,.. etc.) and mark **target** folders as derived in each one of them.

Comment: Ok, so I have 6 matches and only 1 file. Shall I mark *Derived* the three **target** folders and two of the **src** folders?

Comment: Yes or try to close some of the projects that might not be necessary for the build to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old thread, but in the newer Eclipse versions (Photon+) there's a filter option for resource search.

On the Open Resource dialog (Ctrl+Shift+R), click the drop-down on top `"Enter resource name prefix..."` and select `"Filter Duplicated Resources"`.

If you're just looking for Java classes you can also use Open Type dialog (CTRL-Shift-T).

Comment: Yep, a really old thread that I do not really remember since when I switched to IntelliJ...
But maybe it is useful to someone, who knows.